# Is there a way to pad to an even number of digits?

Tags: python, string, padding

I'm trying to create a hex representation of some data that needs to be transmitted (specifically, in ASN.1 notation). At some points, I need to convert data to its hex representation. Since the data is transmitted as a byte sequence, the hex representation has to be padded with a 0 if the length is odd.

Example:

```
>>> hex2(3)
'03'
>>> hex2(45)
'2d'
>>> hex2(678)
'02a6'
```

The goal is to find a simple, elegant implementation for `hex2`.

Currently I'm using `hex`, stripping out the first two characters, then padding the string with a `0` if its length is odd. However, I'd like to find a better solution for future reference. I've looked in `str.format` without finding anything that pads to a multiple.

Comment: I think that's as good as you'll get, except of course if there's a hidden gem in the standard libray...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
def hex2(n):
  x = '%x' % (n,)
  return ('0' * (len(x) % 2)) + x
```

Answer (score 7):

To be totally honest, I am not sure what the issue is. A straightforward implementation of what you describe goes like this:

```
def hex2(v):
  s = hex(v)[2:]
  return s if len(s) % 2 == 0 else '0' + s
```

I would not necessarily call this "elegant" but I would certainly call it "simple."

Comment: If `v` happens to be a `long`, then `hex(v)` will have a trailing `L` and the value returned by this function will also have it.

Answer (score 0):

Python's `binascii` module's `b2a_hex` is guaranteed to return an even-length string.

the trick then is to convert the integer into a bytestring. Python3.2 and higher has that built-in to int:

```
from binascii import b2a_hex

def hex2(integer):
    return b2a_hex(integer.to_bytes((integer.bit_length() + 7) // 8, 'big'))
```

Answer (score -1):

Might want to look at the struct module, which is designed for byte-oriented i/o.

```
import struct
>>> struct.pack('>i',678)
'\x00\x00\x02\xa6'
#Use h instead of i for shorts
>>> struct.pack('>h',1043)
'\x04\x13'
```

Comment: No, this has very little to do with the question. Either delete or update your answer, please.